# Tracking down birth of James Spencer Ward circa 1830s in Wrenbury?

Tags: 19th-century, england, birth-records, cheshire

I am trying to find a birth for a James Spencer Ward in Wrenbury, Cheshire, sometime in the 1830s.

I know that James Spencer Ward lived in Chester as of the 1901, 1891, 1881 and 1871 censuses. His wife was Mary A, which I believe to be Mary Ann Davies (who married a James Ward in Chester in 1864).

His place of birth is listed on censuses as Wrenbury, Cheshire but the age is all over the place, some listing a YOB around 1833 and others a lot later.

A James Spencer Ward died in Chester in 1903 with an estimate birth date of 1837, which I think is the correct one.

I am struggling to find a birth record for him though. If the 1864 marriage is him, then his father was John Ward but I can't find any census records earlier which seem to be congruent.

Comment: This may be him on the [1861 census](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M7L9-28V).

Comment: @sempaiscuba yes I think it might be; I've seen that record but it unfortunately lends no more clues. It strengthens the 1837 figure I suppose

Comment: Does the 1861 address match the 1864 marriage?

Comment: @sempaiscuba I don't have the certificate yet, so can't check. If that's the best avenue I can order it but I'd rather not as the expenses all add up.

Comment: Looking at the [Bishop's transcript](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:N42L-8FP) it seems the addresses don't match. Ah, well ...

Comment: @semapiscuba they're both in Chester, just a different part of town. He may have moved

Comment: That was my thinking too. That's often the way when you're following a paper trail through the records.

Comment: @sempaiscuba there are a few James Wards living in Cheshire in the 1851 census, but none born on Wrenbury from what I can find.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69237/discussion-between-charlie-and-sempaiscuba).